# How to make a anonymous class with void return type method and no parameters into a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, try-catch, runnable

I have the following piece of code where I need to change it into a lambda expression (Sonarlint presents this as an issue)

```
      Runnable runnableObj = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            myObj.setParameters(Id);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Exception in setting parameters for user" + Id);
          }
        }
      }
```

I tried to change this into

```
       Runnable runnableObj = ()->{
          try {
            myObj.setParameters(Id);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Exception in setting parameters for user" + Id);
          }

      }
```

I am not sure if this the correct way to do it.
Please help as I have not implemented lambda expressions previously.

Comment: If it doesn't show any error, you should have try the code to check ;)

Comment: This looks fine to me

Comment: yes, that is correct expressed!

Comment: Re: "I am not sure if this is the correct way..."  What happened when you tried it?  Did you write a test case to see what would happen when it called `runnableObj.run()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct implementation. The lambda expressions takes no arguments as the `run()` method doesn't, and it contains the same implementation.